# Could Use Guidance on an Example Problem for Functional Analysis Final

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm wrapping up my last semester of Functional and my prof gave the class a list of problems to review as "samples" for the final. Well, my officemate and I are both stumped by this last problem. Any guidance y'all could provide would be much appreciated. Here's the last problem:

---

**Let $M_{\varphi}: L^{2}(0,2 \pi) \rightarrow L^{2}(0,2 \pi)$ be defined by $M_{\varphi} f=\varphi f$, where $\varphi(t)=\max (0, \sin t)$.
Find $\sigma_{p}\left(M_{\varphi}\right)$ and $\sigma_{a p}\left(M_{\varphi}\right)$. Prove your answer.**

---

It might be worth noting, we're using Conway's book and the notation is the same as the book's, with:

- $\mathscr{X}$ a Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $A\in\mathscr{B(X)}$, $\mathscr{B(X)}$ is is the space of bounded linear operators from $\mathscr{X}$ to $\mathscr{X}$.
- $\sigma_{p}(A)=\{ \lambda\in\mathbb{C}: \ker(A-\lambda)\neq 0\}$
- $\sigma_{ap}(A)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: \text{ there is a sequence } \{x_{n}\} \text{ in } \mathscr{X} \text{ such that } ||x_{n}||=1 \text{ for all } n \text{ and } ||(A-\lambda)x_{n}||\to 0 \}$

Comment: Keyword "multiplication operator"?!?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $z=a+ib$ and $|z|>1$ then
\begin{align}
|\sin(t)-z|^2 \ge  (|z|-\sin(t))^2\ge c^2>0
\end{align}
on $[0, \pi]$ for some $c$. Then, it follows
\begin{align}
\|(M_\varphi-z) f\|^2 =&\ \int^{\pi}_0 |\sin(t)-z|^2f(t)^2\ dt+\int^{2\pi}_\pi |z|^2f(t)^2\ dt\\
\ge&\ \min(|z|^2, c^2) \|f\|^2
\end{align}
Hence, $M_\varphi-z$ is injective which means $\sigma_{ap}(M_\varphi) \subset \{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|\le 1\}$.

Suppose $|z|\le 1$, then $|a|<1$. If $a<0$ then again
\begin{align}
|z-\sin(t)|^2=(a-\sin(t))^2+b^2\ge \max(a^2, b^2)>0
\end{align}
which reduces to the previous case. So, it suffices to consider $a>0$ and $b=0$. More precisely, consider the function
\begin{align}
g(t) = a-\sin(t)
\end{align}
which vanishes at some $t_\ast \in [0, \pi]$. Next, let $f(t-t_\ast)$ be a compactly supported bump function centered at $t_\ast$ such that $\|f\|=1$ and consider
\begin{align}
f_\varepsilon(t) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon} f(\frac{t-t_\ast}{\varepsilon})
\end{align}
which clearly has norm $1$. Next, observe that
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi}_0 g(t)^2 f_\varepsilon(t)^2\ dt = \int_{|t-t_0|\le \varepsilon} g(t)^2 f_\varepsilon(t)^2\ dt \le \int_{|t-t_0|\le \varepsilon} \varepsilon^2 f_\varepsilon(t)^2\ dt\rightarrow 0
\end{align}
as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. Note that we have used that fact that
\begin{align}
|g(t)| = |g(t)-g(t_\ast)| \le |t-t_\ast|.
\end{align}

I will leave you to finish the rest of the argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, after trying to tear this proof apart, we're not 100% sure we know what's going on here.

Comment: @MattTucker It would be great if you can tell me where you are confused. I will try to elaborate.